# Enable users to edit user profile and nodes in same page

Tags: nodes, users

In my project I would like my users to be able to edit their profile from the same page they view their profile.

In order words when they click on the fields or an edit button beside the fields, they will be able to enter a new value.

What I want to achieve is pretty much how users edit their profile on LinkedIn.

Please is there a module that can help me achieve this?

(Please note that I am displaying the user profile with "views").

Comment: [Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit)

Answer (score 0):

Try these modules
https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit
https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable

And for views, use editableviews

Comment: Constructive feedback, based on my own experiences: link only questions often get downvoted. Consider explaining WHY you recommend these modules. Maybe also add some relevant quotes from the project pages. OK?